# Can I set width or height of <div> to subtraction of a certain percentage?

Tags: html, css

Suppose a `<div>` tag is in a parent `<div>` tag. The parent tag has takes a certain portion of screen; and I want the `width` and `height` tags of the child tag to be something like this: `width: 100% - 100px;`, so that the gap between the child and the parent always remains the same regardless of browser window size.

The codes below are what I'm dealing with.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS styles I put in. It works well with the commented width and height properties but `100% - 100px` just hides the `.inner` selector.

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    height: 84%;
    width: 100%;}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;}

.inner {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: mainbox;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 100% - 100px;//90%
    height: 100% - 100px;//80%
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

@keyframes mainbox{
    from{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 0%;
    }

    to{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        height: 100% - 100px;//80%
    }
}
```

How can I set the gap in the way I want?

Comment: Hi you can use height: calc(100% - 100px);

Comment: this was a pretty easy one.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use the standard [calc() function](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) in CSS. Be aware of it's current browser support, although it's pretty good at this point anyway.

```
.class {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

If you use preprocessors like LESS or SASS, this also works too.

Comment: This is what i have wanted. And can I use some function or method or something to repeatedly use some styles?

Comment: e.g. defining that `100% - 100px` as `pane-size` or something in the CSS code

Comment: for that you will need some preprocessors

Comment: Yes, you'd be best using a preprocessor like SASS if you wanted to use variables.